# Only serialize List property when not empty

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

In web api, I'm serializing a class that contains properties that are `IEnumerable` and I only want the properties to be serialized if they are not empty collections.

`[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` does not work because the properties are not null since they are initialized in the constructor.

```
[DataContract]
public class Linkable : ILinkable {

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public IList<ILink> links { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public IList<ILink> linkTemplates { get; set; }

    public Linkable() {
        links = new List<ILink>();
        linkTemplates = new List<ILink>();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with an `Attribute`? If not, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just leave the collections null until you need to add something to them? For example:

```
public class Linkable {
    public IList<ILink> links { get; set; }

    public void AddLink(ILink link) {
        if (links == null) {
            links = new List<ILink>();
        }
        links.Add(link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or is `Enumerable.Empty` an option?